# Group matched array values

Tags: php

Program:

```
while($i<=$row) {
  echo $arr[$i][1].$arr[$i][4]
}
```

Output

```
Product Code       Qty
KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE 1
KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE 1
KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE 1
KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE 1
KC_SUNGLASSES_BK    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_BK    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_BE    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_BE    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_OE    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_OE    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_RD    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_RD    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_WE    1
KC_SUNGLASSES_WE    1
```

I want it to output

```
KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE 4
KC_SUNGLASSES 10
```

so that it group product code excluding last underscore and sum their quantity

Comment: Could you `var_dump` the entire array for us please? Maybe share how you're populating it?

Comment: What is the structure of `$arr`?

Comment: Also, what about something like `$arr[$i][1]['count'] += $arr[$i][4]` (in case the latter isn't always 1), and then echoing that info.

Comment: basically i am reading a csv file and storing it into array. this is how the code looks like http://pastebin.com/VgNthpy7

Comment: We need to see the contents of the array; not the code that populates the array.

Comment: array content looks like http://oi41.tinypic.com/el18ue.jpg

Comment: Ok, if you want help, you're gonna have to provide what we're asking.  Post the output of `var_dump($arr)` for us, please.

Comment: Sure please. the output of arr is http://pastebin.com/c50CNwmL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$arr` looks something like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array('{something}', 'KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE', '{something}', '{something}', 1),
    array('{something}', 'KC_SUNGLASSES_BK', '{something}', '{something}', 1),
    // ...
);
```

Then you can get the output what you what like this:

```
// we'll store counts here
$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $product = $row[1];
    $qty = $row[4];

    // figure out where the last underscore is and chop off everything that follows it
    // this is VERY brittle. If the product ends up with a name like _SOMEKEY you'll end
    // up with an empty key. Not good. Probably not a huge issue, but buyer beware
    $_product = substr($product, 0, strrpos($product, '_'));

    if (isset($result[$_product])) {
        $result[$_product] += $qty; // we already started counting
    } else {
        $result[$_product] = $qty; // not started counting this product yet, start it
    }
}

// now print your result:
foreach ($result as $id => $qty) {
    echo $id, "\t", $qty, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: looks like it will work. thanks a lot. I tried modifying echo     $id, "\t", $qty, PHP_EOL; to display in table //echo "<tr><td>".$id."</td><td align='center'>".$aty."</td></tr>"; but looks like i am doing something wrong

Comment: sorry my mistake :) $qty Thanks a lot for your help